# Representing owl data in JUNG graph and compute Page Rank with Prior

Tags: graph, ontology, jung

I am loading the owl data into a JUNG graph in order to compute the PageRank with prior algorithm.

I created a JUNG graph for the ontology

```
        // vertices: RDFNodes, edges: Statements
        //Graph<RDFNode, Statement> g = new JenaJungGraph(model);

        DirectedGraph<RDFNode,Statement> g = new DirectedSparseGraph<RDFNode,Statement>();

        String resource = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\camera.owl";
        Model m = FileManager.get().loadModel(resource);
        m.write(System.out);

          StmtIterator iter = m.listStatements();

            // print out the predicate, subject and object of each statement
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Statement stmt      = iter.nextStatement();         // get next statement
                RDFNode subject   = stmt.getSubject();   // get the subject
                RDFNode object    = stmt.getObject();    // get the object

                g.addVertex( subject);

               if(object instanceof Resource || !object.isLiteral())
               {

                g.addVertex( object );
                g.addEdge( stmt, subject, object, EdgeType.DIRECTED);  

            }
            }

                Collection<RDFNode> collectionOfVertices = g.getVertices();

                System.out.println("number of vertices:" + collectionOfVertices.size());
                System.out.println("number of edges:" +g.getEdgeCount());

 }
```

}

Now I want to compute the PageRank with Prior for this graph. How to compute this one? Any hints?

Comment: Without additional details such as what your ontology looks like and how you expect to use the pagerank with priors algorithm, i.e, what nodes you say should be biased, we cannot really give you any additional help. Go check out [this](https://sites.google.com/site/nirajatweb/home/technical_and_coding_stuff/page-rank-with-prior) though, it may help you out a bit.

Comment: Kunal, The loading RDFdata could be very ontology, i.e camera.owl, and then I need to compute the score of nodes and edges for this graph.

Comment: Kunal, The loading RDF data could be every ontology, i.e camera.owl. Subjects and objects of RDF Triples have to be mapped into Nodes of JUNG graph and Predicates of RDF Triples into Edges. Once we get this mapping, we need to compute then the score of nodes and edges.

Comment: Ok from your code it looks like you have the mapping figured out, have you decided what your root nodes are? What probability you would like them to have? And what your backpropogation probability is?

Comment: The root set encompasses the entire graph. Node transition probabilities are to be defined by the vertex weights while edge transition probabilities are to be defined by the edge weights.

Comment: The fact that you're making a distinction between node transition probabilities and edge transition probabilities suggests that you don't quite understand how the algorithm works.  You should also clarify whether the problem is (a) you don't understand how to use the PageRankWithPriors API at all (in which case Kunal's link should be useful), or (b) the results you're getting are not what you expected.

Comment: Joshua, my problem is the implementation of the algorithm. More concrete, the computation of edge_weigths, vertex_rootSet (from the Kunal's link) for this ontology graph.

Comment: The root set is an input (the PRWR implementation requires you to specify a distribution over the root set which must sum to 1).  So are the edge weights.  You need to decide how those should be defined. http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/scoring/PageRankWithPriors.html